# Slowly changing side input stops working with larger dataset

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

EDIT:  As far as I can tell, all the elements are added. I tried adding a reshuffle and missing with the sequence but no luck.  I added more of my source code here:  https://github.com/nathan-smit/dataflowpipelinecode

[image]

I'm currently using Apache Beam SDK for Java 2.42.0 on Google Cloud Dataflow. I have a slowly changing side input that I'm reading in from a BigQuery table.  This is what the side input looks like:

```
        final PCollectionView<Map<String, String>> skus = pipeline
                // Emitted long data trigger this batch read BigQuery client job.
                .apply(String.format("Read big query central sku table.  Updating every %s hours", 10),
                        GenerateSequence.from(0).withRate(1, Duration.standardHours(10)))
                .apply(
                        Window.<Long>into(new GlobalWindows())
                                .triggering(Repeatedly.forever(AfterProcessingTime.pastFirstElementInPane()))
                                .discardingFiredPanes()) // Caching results as Map.

                .apply(new ReadSlowChangingBigQueryTable("Read BigQuery SKU Table", query,
                        "sku_id",
                        "sku_code"))
                // Caching results as Map.
                .apply("Sku View As Map", View.asMap());
```

"ReadSlowChangingBigQueryTable" fetches two columns and returns these as KV pairs.

```
                for (FieldValueList row : result.iterateAll()) {
                    String keyInstance = row.get(key).getStringValue();
                    String valueInstance = row.get(value).getStringValue();
                    
                    c.output(KV.of(keyInstance, valueInstance));
                }
```

I'm using this side input as a lookup which looks like the below where I'm looking up a corresponding code for this id.  I was running this with 10000 rows from BigQuery without issue, however, as I've tried to add more rows it seems that my lookup stops working even though the absolute amount of data for all rows (500k rows) is +- 15mb i.e. when I try to enrich the row skuTable.get(sku) returns null.

Is there a better way to do what I'm attempting here? I'm uncertain if the pipeline is just slow or if it'll never complete as all of the elements are placed in the view as map step, but the lookup doesn't return the expected result.

```
   @ProcessElement
    public void ProcessElement(ProcessContext c) {

        skuTable = c.sideInput(skus);
        String sku = c.element().getSku();

        if (skuTable.containsKey(sku)) {
          c.output(
            new BranchCompanySkuTransactionValue(
              c.element().getBranch(),
              c.element().getCompany(),
              skuTable.get(sku),
              c.element().getTransactionId(),
              c.element().getTable(),
              c.element().getOp(),
              c.element().getTs_ms(),
              c.element().getValue()
            )
          );
        }
  }
```

Edit:  There is also this recommendation in the Dataflow console
[image]

Comment: Are all the documents read, the only problem is when using the side input? Or the input never finishes computing? As a test, what happens if you try to have it fixed (without GenerateSequence)? The high fan-out might be problematic, indeed, and you can force a fusion break by using [Reshuffle](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/current/org/apache/beam/sdk/transforms/Reshuffle.html).

Comment: As far as I can see, all the elements are passed into the "Sku View As Map" step (I can see +- 500k events) but when I run skuTable.get(sku) it returns null.  If I run the exact same pipelien with just 10k records extracted everything runs correctly.  I will try your suggestions and report back

Comment: @BrunoVolpato So I tried a couple of things on my side without success.  I then looped through the sku table and logged the output and I could see a bunch of key value pairs.  I then added a log for the size of the map and it looks like that's the issue as no matter how long I wait the skuTable size stays at 3406 so I'm guessing I'm maxing something out?

Comment: It doesn't ring any bells. Did you try to add the reshuffle and see if it improves?

Comment: @BrunoVolpato I did do the shuffle but didn't have any improvement.  I think I managed to get closer to the source of the issue yesterday.  I changed my process to not be Slowly Changing which allowed me to use BigQueryIO instead of my own DoFn and that process correctly loaded in all of the data without issue.  I'm guessing then that it's something specific to my DoFn but not certain yet what that might be